# How to find files in linux, given a certain pattern?

Tags: bash

So I have to answer this question for homework:

Which command line must be supplied in Terminal in order to find all "c" source files that contain in their name as first three characters "lab" (all uppercase, lowercase, or any combination), followed then by a number between 1 and 299, and then by #,%, or #.

I think I'm supposed to use grep, and not find.

Comment: How you can determine if the file is "c" file ? by extension ?

Comment: By extention, yes

Comment: Broadly speaking, `grep` matches within the _content_ of files whereas `find` searches the filesystem by file _name_ (amongst other things). Since it's homework it would be good to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean by matching "_by #, %, or #_"? How is that different to matching "by # or %"?

Comment: Are the files just in your current directory or could they be scattered across the filesystem? If it's the former a shell glob will match them implicitly. If it's the latter than something like `find` will be required.

Comment: I've only tried using grep and either there was no result either i would get the error 'grep . : Is a directory'.
The files can be scattered across the filesystem.

Comment: Please show that you made some attempt to solve the problem on your own, e.g. by scanning the documentations (man pages) of both utilities. This should make pretty clear to you whether to use `grep` or `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls` to recursively list files and pipe its input to `grep` that can filter result based on regular expression:

```
sudo ls -R  / | grep -i -e '^lab\([12][0-9][0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\|[1-9]\)[#%]\.c$'
```

The `grep` command uses `-i` option to ignore cases and `-e` to treat the next argument as regular expression to search for. The `ls` command's `-R` option is for telling `ls` to list files recursively.

Comment: That'll match something like `lab` or `lab2#xyzzy` as well as the required files.

Comment: @roaima no it won't as the regular expression matches for `.c` extension immediately after matching for `#%` and `#` and makes sure that file names end after that.

Comment: Sorry, misread the expression late at night. It does wrongly match `lab22` and `lab999#.c` though.

Comment: @Overload94:  There are a few errors including those mentioned by roaima.  Hopefully you won't mind that I fix it.